# Task<T> vs Asynchronous delegates in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have this simple method :

```
static int Work (string s) { return s.Length; }
```

I could run it with  :

```
Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<int> (() => Work ("lalala") );
...
int result = task.Result;
```

Or with this  :

```
Func<string, int> method = Work;
IAsyncResult myIasync= method.BeginInvoke ("lalala", null, null);
...
int result = method.EndInvoke (myIasync);
```

- They both use a threadpool thread.
- Both wait the execution to finish ( when reading the value)
- Both rethrow any exception to the caller.

When Should I use each ?

Comment: I assume the Task is better since it is newer, but I hardly believe there will be any difference with this tiny code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The second form, using `IAsyncResult`, is significantly older, and much less powerful. `Task<T>` was introduced in .NET 4, and is the preferred way of representing asynchronous operations now. It's much simpler to use, particularly in C# 5 which supports "asynchronous functions" where you can await a task (or other asynchronous operation) in a non-blocking way.

Using a `Task` instead of calling `BeginInvoke` probably won't change much about how the operation itself is executed (although it gives you more options in terms of scheduling etc), but it makes a huge difference from the perspective of the code which wants to "watch" the operation, use the results, wait for multiple tasks, handle failures etc.

If you can possibly use C# 5 (either with .NET 4.5, or with .NET 4 plus the async targeting pack) it will make your life considerably easier when it comes to managing asynchronous operations. It's the way forward :)

Comment: Thanks.Let's say the task is taking very long time to execute. Does it tie a threadpool thread until it finishes ( so now the threadpool has [n-1] threads) ? or the work is delegated to  a non-threadpool-thread , and only when done , it's gets back to a threadpool thread... ?

Comment: @AutoExec.Bat: If you use `Task`, you can tell it that it's a long-running task, in which case it would use a non-threadpool thread. It's not clear what you mean by "it's gets back to a threadpool thread". Does *what* go back to a thread-pool thread?

Comment: A job has to be made. it's a long job. this job could either be executed with a threadpool-thread , **or** it can be transfered to a **non-threadpool** thread ( so now the thread is _back_ to the pool - to server other requests) , and when the job is finished ( in the non-threadpool-thread) - it signals : _"hey I finished the job "_ and the control is back to a threadpool thread. (the idea is to save threadpool threads from being wasted).So my question is : how does _Task vs IAsync_ work in that manner...(does the actual job is mad by a threadpool or nonthreadpool thread ?)

Comment: p.s. Now i've seen( as you mentioned ) that task has `LongRunning` flag which does exactly it. So the **remainning** question is about Async Delegate. Thank you :-)

Comment: @AutoExec.Bat: "The control is back to a threadpool thread" - what control? I think you need to step back and think about what each thread is actually doing. Using `BeginInvoke` on a delegate always uses thread-pool threads, I believe.

Comment: Yout last sentence answered my question.FYI :  I was talking about how the asynchronous operation itself is working.When the asynchronous operation finishes, it will call this method, giving you the same IAsyncResult as before. At this point, you can retrieve your state object from it, or pass the IAsyncResult to EndInvoke. If it hasn't finished yet, it'll block until it does but if it did end - The operation continues.

Answer (score 0):

Task is more elegant, and was introduced more recently (.Net 4) so if it meets your needs, I'd go with that.