# Threading.Tasks Dispose meaning issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I would like to integrate in my application the `Tasks` Class usage because is the one that I know accomplish my requeriments as I only need to launch one very simple asynchronous operation to call a safe WinAPI method, then if I use a background worker that would be a very huge solution and just insane in my opinnion only to run one instruction in this way:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() NativeMethods.SomeWrapper)
```

I need to execute that instruction much times per minute (like 100), but I can't wait for the asynchronous operation to finish and dispose the object using the `Wait` method because even if the current `Task` is alive my intention is to launch another `Task` instance of the same operation and let the old task still working, so I don't know whether the `GarbageCollector` will dispose my `Task` objects automatically when each task finishes or I need to dispose each one manualy using the `Dispose` method?, in that case I'm very lost 'cause I don't know how to in this circunstances that I mentioned.

I'm a little bit confused with that method, I've tried for curiosity this very simple test below, each time that I execute this loop the memory increases around 20 mb in my case and I don't see that consumption gets disposed never, anyways, I'm not a profiler experto but as all the .NET experts knows the memory consumption indicators for a vb.net app could be very inefficient, so I still consufe even with this little test below:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To 99999
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() NativeSafeMethods.SomeSafeWrapper)
Next
```

Please someone get me out of doubt.

Comment: If you're wondering about this because you were previously required to call EndInvoke to avoid leaks, please see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698129/taskt-vs-asynchronous-delegates-in-c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Task.Dispose` exists to dispose of an internal wait handle that is used if you perform blocking operations on the `Task` (like calling `Wait()`). If you don't do that, there's no point in calling `Dispose`.

With tasks, it is generally recommended to *not* call `Dispose` unless you've got that very specific scenario and it is causing performance problems. If there's a wait handle and you don't `Dispose`, there's no harm -- it will be picked up by the GC at some point.

Comment: Thankyou, very two different answers for this question that are very useful, I don't know which to mark as accepted, both helped me to understand different ad important things.

Answer (score 4):

The GC will *always* be able to clean up resources that are no longer accessible through your application.  You never need to do anything special to enable this.  Disposal is very explicitly for unmanaged resources that *aren't* within the GC's realm of responsibility.  Tasks, specifically, don't need to be disposed.  You don't need to worry about cleaning them up after you start them.

Of course, just because the GC *can* clean up managed resources doesn't necessarily mean it will do so right away.  It's free to do so whenever it feels the need to do so.  You should let it optimize itself; trying to force it to act will, in most cases, only ever cause you problems.